# w3 Total Cache Cross-browser problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I have designed a website using Wordpress and caching it with W3 Total Cache. I have experience with them both but I encountered the next problem.

The website http://atelieruldigital.com is a one page website, with another page for the partners of the program (http://atelieruldigital.com/parteneri/). When I access the partner page, everything loads as it should. When I access the main page by clicking "Acasă" or the logo, I have the next behaviors:

1. Google Chrome: everything loads as it should;
2. Mozilla Firefox: the scripts have lots of errors in the console and the page loads broken. I have to refresh (F5) to make it work as intended;
3. Microsoft Edge: the same problem as Mozilla.

I am using manually minifying, only by combining the scripts, excepting the mobile-menu.js, which grants error when I try to combine it. I do not use page caching, only object and browser caching. The theme is a custom theme, based on Twenty Sixteen.

If I disable the caching plugin, everything works as intended. But I need it to help the page load faster.

Comment: better try on this dedicated [site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I will post there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution after a couple of days of debugging. It seems like when manually combining the .js files, I had to switch around some in the load order.